# How make stylistic buttons windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, button, aero

I want use buttons on my application like this (see picture).

This isn't usual buttons, it have standard picture, caption and description.

Could anyone help me with it? (Post some code or something else)

[image]

Comment: If image don't open, try this link: http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/1144/clipbd5.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button you mentioned is called a **Command Link**

Windows Vista and Version 6.00 introduced another kind of push button, **the command link**.
Visually, a command link is very different from a normal push button, but it has the same functionality.
A command link typically displays an arrow icon, a line of text, and additional text in a smaller font.

Here is a list of *styles available for buttons*.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951(VS.85).aspx

Note the constant `BS_COMMANDLINK` and `BS_DEFCOMMANDLINK` at the above weppage

If you create a button using the `BUTTON` class with the `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx` function, you can specify any of the button styles listed

[Design concepts for Command Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511455.aspx)

Check this link to see the various *types of buttons*.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775947(VS.85).aspx

---

Here is the code example for creating a Command Link in C#
[Vista Command Link Control with C# / Windows Forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/03/12/command_5f00_link.aspx)

Hope this helps.